# xCode 6 cannot locate matching signing assets for archived (only) build of app

Tags: ios, xcode6, code-signing, provisioning

I am trying to export an ad-hoc version of an archived build of my app. When I do so I get the following error.

> Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and
>   failed to do so because of the following issues.
>
> No matching provisioning profiles found for "Application/TheApp.app"
>
> None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified
>   entitlements: keychain-access-groups, com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers.

I have tried recreating certificates, recreating and importing provisioning profiles into Xcode, and recreating the developer profile - basically following any suggestion on stack overflow that I could find. Nothing seems to be accepted by xCode.

The thing that makes this situation somewhat unique is that I cannot readily just rebuild the app. It is an old archive, and if I can't create the ad-hoc version from the archive, I can't create it at all.

Prior to xCode 6, I did this all the time without issue. But with xCode 6 and this new error, I am concerned that I may have deleted something that I need, or will otherwise be unable to export this ad-hoc version.

Understanding that I cannot re-build this app, and need to work off of this archive only, is there a way that I can provide the provisioning profile xCode is looking for?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct distribution certificate and profile for that? If yes, then please delete all the provisioning profiles from your xcode. Download the latest profile that you want to use. If you are part of a multiple team in your developer's account, make sure there are only valid username and password there.

Comment: I used an ad-hoc distribution certificate and code-signed. Since then, I have had to create, download and add/import all new provisioning profiles since the existing ones expired. I am not part of a team.

Comment: Then make sure you have valid p12 in your keychain.

Comment: I have an active/valid "iPhone Distribution" Certificate/Key p12 and and an active/valid "iPhone Development" Certificate/Key p12 in my Keychain. I also have an expired one of each of those in the Keychain that I have not deleted. Afraid to delete anything at this point.

Comment: I should note that I can successfully export the last several archived builds of my app to create ad-hoc versions. It is an archived build from two years ago that is giving me this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old archive had been created when iCloud was enabled for the App ID. So I had to re-enable iCloud for the App ID, recreate the provisioning profile, and install the provisioning file in order to create the ad-hoc .ipa and install the ad-hoc app on a device. This was for testing. When testing was done, I disabled iCloud for the App ID and recreated all of the profiles.